A property of image of a ring homomorphism
Recently I was asked the following question in a competitive exam:
Let ${R}$ and ${S}$ be two commutative rings with multiplicative identity ${1_R}$ and ${1_S}$ respectively. Let ${f}$ :${R}$ $\to$ ${S}$ be a ring homomorphism with ${f}$ ${({1_R})}$ ${=}$ ${1_S}$. Which of the following statements are true ?
1) If ${f}$ ${({a})}$ is a unit in ${S}$ for every non-zero element ${a}$ $\in$ ${R}$, then ${S}$ is a field.
2) If ${f}$ ${({a})}$ is a unit in ${S}$ for every non-zero element ${a}$ $\in$ ${R}$, then ${f}$ ${({R})}$ is a field.
3) If ${R}$ is a field, then ${f}$ ${({a})}$ is a unit in ${S}$ for every non-zero element ${a}$ $\in$ ${R}$.
4) If ${a}$ is a unit in ${R}$, then ${f}$ ${({a})}$ is a unit in ${S}$.
It seems to me that 2, 3, 4 are correct but the answer key says that option 3 and 4 are only correct. I do not understand what is wrong in my reasoning for option 2, which is as follows-
Clearly ${1_S}$ $\in$ ${f}$ ${({R})}$  as ${f}$ ${({1_R})}$ ${=}$ ${1_S}$ . Furthermore ${f}$ ${({a})}$ $\neq$ ${0}$ implies ${a}$ $\neq$ ${0}$ which in turn implies that ${f}$ ${({a})}$ is a unit, hence ${f}$ ${({R})}$ is a field.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Hint: What if $S$ and $R$ are the zero ring?

Also, consider the inclusions of the integers in the rationales. I.e. You might be missing your inverses in the source space as they only exist in the target.
